# The output of the function should be double but it gives me integer

Tags: c++, function, double, user-defined-functions

I made a program which is actually good and working and it has a user defined function in it but there is only one problem as it's shown in the title, I got integer output instead of double, I don't know why and I tried everything I know but ended up failing.

Why is the result of the function a whole integer and not a double?

> Write a function `main()` that prompts the user to enter three integers number, lower, and upper then calls the function `average()`: 
>   `double average( int howManyNumbers, int lower, int upper)`
>   which generates `howManyNumbers` random integers in the range lower and upper inclusive. The function then finds and returns the average of the randomly generated integers. The function should generate different set of values for each run.

And this is my program's code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<ctime>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int number,lower,upper;
    double average (int , int , int);
    cout<<"Enter number, lower, upper: ";
    cin>>number>>lower>>upper;
    cout<<showpoint<<fixed;
    cout<<"The average of the "<<number<<" random integers is"<<average(number,lower,upper );
    return 0;
}

double average (int howManyNumbers, int lower, int upper)
{
    int i;
    double avg,sum=0;
    for (i=0;i<howManyNumbers;i++)
        {
            srand(time(0));
            sum=sum+(lower+rand()%(upper-lower+1));
        }

    avg=(sum/howManyNumbers);
    return avg;
}
```

Comment: `(lower+rand()%(upper-lower+1))` all of this arithmetic only involves integers.

Comment: Sometimes, a `(double)3.0` would be output as `3` but it is still a `double` internally

Comment: I really doubt that for `average(100,0,100 )` gives an integer. `avg=(sum/howManyNumbers);` is not an integer aritmetic.

Comment: `avg=(sum/(double)howManyNumbers);` Whenever you want a floating point result, make sure all of the values you are working with are floating point as well. Arithmetic operators with integers can cause everything to get truncated to an integer before being implicitly cast back to a float.

Comment: @DarkZeros
you can make the avg double by multiply it by 1.0 
like this  : "avg=1.0*(sum/howManyNumbers)
since "sum/howManyNumbers" gives integer , multiply it by 1.0 to be double. (As I get it from my doctor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the `srand(time(0));` to before the loop.

With `srand(time(0));` you re-initialise the random number generator on each loop and this results in the same result from the call to `rand()` in each iteration of the `for` loop, thus adding the same number to the `sum` `howManyNumbers` number of times.

Hence when divided by `howManyNumbers`, it gives a "whole" integer back (or near enough that the error is not displayed given the precision used).

Simply;

```
srand(time(0)); // moved to before the loop.
for (i=0;i<howManyNumbers;i++)
{
  // ...
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a7c579d95eea1dd6)

Comment: It worked perfectly, thx alot for the info and thx for the explanation ^^

Answer (score 3):

you have to call  `srand(time(0));` only one time and you will get a double result.

```
 srand(time(0));
 for (i=0;i<howManyNumbers;i++)
 {
     sum=sum+(lower+rand()%(upper-lower+1));
 }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot bro it really worked and it gave me a double value.
but can you tell me what exactly happened when I Moved srand(time(0)) outside the loop?

Comment: following link explains why you should initialize srand only one time for the whole session for generating different numbers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620163/use-of-srand-in-c