# c++ rand() only generating 8 between 1-10

Tags: c++, random

I'm trying to generate a random number between 1-10 to then have my switch statement to output a random day of the week, but I can't get it to output any other number except for 8.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a = rand() % 10 + 1;
    cout << a << endl;
    if (a != 4)
    { cout << endl << "a is less than 4" << endl;}
    else
    { cout << endl << "a is greater than or equal to 4";}


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look up srand in your textbook. Better yet, look up the features declared in the `<random>` header.

Comment: a != 4 does NOT imply "a is less than 4"

Comment: You need run srand() to seeds the pseudo-random number generator used by rand(). [srand](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/srand)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [use of srand() in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620163/use-of-srand-in-c)

Comment: @HarrisonStott If your question was adequately answered you can mark it as resolved by clicking the check mark next to the answer you found most useful.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `srand(time(nullptr))` before `rand()`.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`srand()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/rand-and-srand-in-ccpp/) to seed `rand()` before using it.

The output of `rand()` is dependent on the seed used. The same default seed is being used each time you run your program resulting in the same output each time.

A common way to seed rand is with time:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

int main() {

    // Use current time as seed for random generator
    srand(time(0));

    // Do stuff with rand()

}
```

This way you get different results every time you run your program, because the time will be different every time the program is executed.

Answer (score 2):

Initialize random seed and proceed.

```
int main()
{
    srand (time(NULL));

    int a = rand() % 10 + 1;

    cout << a << endl;
    if (a < 4)
    {
        cout << endl << "a is less than 4" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << endl << "a is greater than or equal to 4";}
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: And note that if this program is run twice with very little time between runs it can still produce the same value both times because of the granularity of the `time()` function. Real-world programs take long enough to run that you don't hit this, but simple test programs like this one can be fooled. Upvoted.